# Visualize weighted graph (with weights as distances between vertices) in 2D space

Tags: python, graph

I have a weighted adjacency list where the weights are the distances between the vertices. I'd like to visualize this by translating each vertex into an x, y coordinate.

Is there an algorithm that will take this adjacency list and plot in 2D space such that the graph is consistent with the list (i.e. all graph lines are the length prescribed by the distance weights)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the answer is no, you cannot plot a *general* graph in 2d while precisely preserving distances.

The reason is that in order to be able to embed a graph without distortion of distances, the distances must have very special properties. For example, they must fulfill the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality), amongst other things.

To see this, consider a graph with 3 vertices A,B,C and distances d(A,B)=1 d(B,C)=2 d(A,C)=5. You can easily see that this will not work. In fact, you won't be able to embed this in *ANY* Euclidean space, regardless of the dimension!

What you can do is the following: Try to reduce the dimensionality (embed the graph in a 2d space) by using an algorithm like [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis). PCA is widely used and you can easily find implementations in any programming language you prefer. It will give you some representation in 2D, but is not guaranteed to maintain the distances. However, if your graph happens to have distances that are consistent with a 2D embedding, the PCA could find it.

BTW, applying PCA directly to distances is sometimes called [Multidimensional Scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling) (MDS).